# coalesce in view is not using proper join order

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below query works fine i.e. uses index and right join order and method

```
pgdb=> explain analyze SELECT ces.cesp, cm.cpk, ces.hmnc, pip.pn, cm.df,
pgdb->     COALESCE(cm.mid, 'CUST'::character varying) AS mid
pgdb->    FROM oc.ces ces
pgdb->      JOIN op.pip pip ON pip.pip_pk = ces.pip_fk
pgdb->      LEFT JOIN oc.cm cm ON cm.cpk = ces.cm_fk AND cm.df = '0'::bpchar
pgdb->   WHERE 1 = 1 AND ces.edt > '2016-11-30'::date AND ces.flg = true and mid = 'C123';
                                                                                          QUERY PLAN

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=1.53..856.50 rows=2 width=192) (actual time=9.439..10.322 rows=3 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.12..855.64 rows=2 width=222) (actual time=8.159..8.171 rows=3 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using ix_cm_mid on cm cm  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=82) (actual time=5.068..5.069 rows=1 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((mid)::text = 'C123'::text)
               Filter: (df = '0'::bpchar)
         ->  Index Scan using fk_ces_cm_n on ces ces  (cost=0.69..846.48 rows=71 width=205) (actual time=3.087..3.097 rows=3 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (cm_fk = cm.cpk)
               Filter: (flg AND (edt > '2016-11-30'::date))
   ->  Index Scan using pk_pip on pip pip  (cost=0.41..0.43 rows=1 width=83) (actual time=0.713..0.714 rows=1 loops=3)
         Index Cond: (pip_pk = ces.pip_fk)
 Planning Time: 0.612 ms
 Execution Time: 10.388 ms
(12 rows)
```

But when same query is put in a view, its using a different plan where its changing the join order and not working efficiently.

```
pgdb=> create or replace view public.v1 as
pgdb->  SELECT ces.cesp, cm.cpk, ces.hmnc, pip.pn, cm.df,
pgdb->     COALESCE(cm.mid, 'CUST'::character varying) AS mid
pgdb-> --    cm.mid
pgdb->    FROM oc.ces ces
pgdb->      JOIN op.pip pip ON pip.pip_pk = ces.pip_fk
pgdb->      LEFT JOIN oc.cm cm ON cm.cpk = ces.cm_fk AND cm.df = '0'::bpchar
pgdb->   WHERE 1 = 1 AND ces.edt > '2016-11-30'::date AND ces.flg = true;
CREATE VIEW
pgdb=> explain analyze  select * from public.v1 where mid = 'C123';
                                                                               QUERY PLAN

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------
 Gather  (cost=1000.97..4676008.20 rows=2 width=192) (actual time=109844.932..150085.920 rows=3 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.97..4675008.00 rows=1 width=192) (actual time=128845.440..150074.647 rows=1 loops=3)
         ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.56..4675007.57 rows=1 width=222) (actual time=128845.401..150074.599 rows=1 loops=3)
               Filter: ((COALESCE(cm.mid, 'CUST'::character varying))::text = 'C123'::text)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 2348376
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on ces ces  (cost=0.00..2467721.06 rows=2908281 width=205) (actual time=1.027..7765.214 rows=2348377 loops=3)
                     Filter: (flg AND (edt > '2016-11-30'::date))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 5502785
               ->  Index Scan using pk_cm on cm cm  (cost=0.56..0.75 rows=1 width=82) (actual time=0.060..0.060 rows=1 loops=7045130)
                     Index Cond: (cpk = ces.cm_fk)
                     Filter: (df = '0'::bpchar)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 0
         ->  Index Scan using pk_pip on pip pip  (cost=0.41..0.43 rows=1 width=83) (actual time=0.039..0.039 rows=1 loops=3)
               Index Cond: (pip_pk = ces.pip_fk)
 Planning Time: 0.656 ms
 Execution Time: 150086.004 ms
(18 rows)
```

But when coalese is not used the same view works fine. Unable to under this difference in behavior due to coalesce, this is postgresql 11.17. Please advise.

```
pgdb=> create or replace view public.v1 as
pgdb->  SELECT ces.cesp, cm.cpk, ces.hmnc, pip.pn, cm.df,
pgdb-> --    COALESCE(cm.mid, 'CUST'::character varying) AS mid
pgdb->     cm.mid
pgdb->    FROM oc.ces ces
pgdb->      JOIN op.pip pip ON pip.pip_pk = ces.pip_fk
pgdb->      LEFT JOIN oc.cm cm ON cm.cpk = ces.cm_fk AND cm.df = '0'::bpchar
pgdb->   WHERE 1 = 1 AND ces.edt > '2016-11-30'::date AND ces.flg = true;
CREATE VIEW
pgdb=> explain analyze select * from public.v1 where mid = 'C123';
                                                                                          QUERY PLAN

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=1.53..856.50 rows=2 width=175) (actual time=0.069..0.093 rows=3 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.12..855.64 rows=2 width=222) (actual time=0.055..0.063 rows=3 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using ix_cm_mid on cm cm  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=82) (actual time=0.028..0.029
rows=1 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((mid)::text = 'C123'::text)
               Filter: (df = '0'::bpchar)
         ->  Index Scan using fk_ces_cm_n on ces ces  (cost=0.69..846.48 rows=71 width=205) (actual
time=0.024..0.030 rows=3 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (cm_fk = cm.cpk)
               Filter: (flg AND (edt > '2016-11-30'::date))
   ->  Index Scan using pk_pip on pip pip  (cost=0.41..0.43 rows=1 width=83) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=3)
         Index Cond: (pip_pk = ces.pip_fk)
 Planning Time: 0.740 ms
 Execution Time: 0.155 ms
(12 rows)
```

Comment: Because of the WHERE condition on mid = 'C123' in your first query, you turn the LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN. Using the view, the database has to execute the query in the view first to get the result from COALESCE, and then check for mid = 'C123', see the FILTER. These are just two (very) different queries.

Answer (score 0):

This is as simple as the rules when an index *can be used*

For an indexed column with an equal predicate an index can be used

```
explain 
select * from t where id = '1';

Index Scan using t_idx on t  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=105)
  Index Cond: (id = '1'::text)
```

If the column is used in some function call as in your case in `coalesce` **index can't be used**. A *sequential scan of the table* is the consequence, which you observe in the degradation of the preformance.

```
explain 
select * from t where coalesce(id,'x') = '1';

Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..298.00 rows=50 width=105)
  Filter: (COALESCE(id, 'x'::text) = '1'::text)
```

You'll have to define a *function based* index with the same expression as in the predicate to use `Index Scan`:

```
create index t_idx2 on t(coalesce(id,'x'));  


explain 
select * from t where coalesce(id,'x') = '1';

Index Scan using t_idx2 on t  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=105)
  Index Cond: (COALESCE(id, 'x'::text) = '1'::text)
```